# How can I know if a kernel buffer comes from the stack?

Tags: linux-kernel

Is there any way to determine whether a buffer received as a void* pointer comes from the stack or has been allocated with any other mechansim (vmalloc, kmalloc, ...)?

In other words, is there any API or trick, similar to is_vmalloc_addr, to know if the buffer comes from the stack?

Comment: Why would you need to know this? As a general rule, you are supposed to just have your data, and do what you want to it, not based on where it is allocated... And even if there was a solution, I doubt it would be portable. Voted to Close.

Comment: I want to pass buffers to another component which has its own memory space (MMU, etc). The current implementation works with buffers allocated with kmalloc, vmalloc, ... but does not with buffers from the stack. The question is two-fold: I want to be able to return not supported as a temporary workaround and also debug this behavior.

Comment: I don't understand why it would work with an address allocated from `kmalloc()/vmalloc()` if the two components have their own memory address? How are you sharing virtual addresses then?

Comment: Each world map the same physical pages (corresponding to the buffer) with the same cache/whatnot attributes in their own virtual memory space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `object_is_on_stack()` at [include/linux/sched.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.9/include/linux/sched.h#L2419). Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks good. I don't know how I could miss this one. I'll try it out. Thanks!